# SQL Server Database Project incompatible in VS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, database-project, sql-server-data-tools

I am running Visual Studio 2013 (which apparently has SQL Server Data Tools built in), but my **SQL Server Database Project will not load (incompatible)**.  This all happened after an update from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1.

I get the following report when trying to reload the project

[image: Migration Report]

When I try to create a new database project, I get the following error:

[image]

When checking "About Visual Studio", the tools are installed:

[image: About Visual Studio]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried a repair of Visual Studio? I don't remember any issues after updating to 8.1, but that's probably the first thing I'd try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repair didn't work. I reinstalled VS and now it is fine.  Painful.

Answer (score 0):

A repair for Visual Studio(from Control Panel) followed by an update for SQL Server Data Tools (Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates) where enough for me in this case